# Ошибки при соединении Qt и MySQL (x64)

Tags: mysql, qt, path, mingw-w64

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Пытаюсь подключить MySQL к Qt. Прописал путь к lib и к include MySQL - **qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\mysql\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\mysql\lib"**. Следующим пунктом делаю - **nmake sub-mysql**. Выходи ошибка - **'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**. Что делать, как быть?

Попробовал mingw32-make.exe пишет -  **'mingw32-make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.** Прописал путь в path - C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin - не помогло та же ошибка

Comment: mingw32-make.exe

Comment: Прописал mingw32-make.exe теперь выдало - 'mingw32-make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Все, спасибо Sergey Tatarincev. mingw32-make.exe решило вопрос. Надо было прописать еще путь в path к mingw32-make.exe (у меня - C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin) и перезагрузить консоль... Путь я прописал, а консоль не перезагрузил, поэтому он мне лепил ту же ошибку еще раз, после перезапуска консоли эта ошибка ушла.